# Narrow band band-pass filter design with LM358 op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter, single-supply-op-amp, band-pass, sallen-key

I am trying to design a narrowband band-pass filter with an LM358 op-amp, single supply 0-5 V. My requirement is a gain of 30 dB at center frequency 4 kHz and 20 dB attenuation at 3 kHz and 5 kHz.

I have tried different topologies and faced problems.

1. Sallen-Key bandpass filter realized by cascading high pass and low pass. The problem observed is a constant 8 kHz signal without any AC input.

[image]

2. Multi-feedback band pass filter. The problem is the output vanishes when an instrumentation amplifier is placed before the filter.

[image]

Is there a solution to this? I am trying the Thomas-Tow topology right now.

Comment: For a bandpass filter in S&K topology - why on earth are you using two stages (lowpass, highpass)? There are S&K bandpass circuits with one opamp only! The same applies to the Multi-feedback circuits. More than that, when you need a single bandpass - why the T&T topology with 3 opamps?

Comment: How do you generate your 2.5V mid-supply voltage?

Comment: Please clean up your schematics, especially the first.

Comment: Pretty high Q, assuming you mean -20dB not 30dB - 20dB. LM358 can't come close with 3 stage (6th order) MFB topology (about 1/50th the required GBW). Your first schematic sort-of works (center frequency and gain is roughly correct) but filter bandwidth is nowhere close.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Can you explain what you meant by -20dB? Also can you explain the point about the gain-bandwidth point? I think that point will help me to debug the circuit. The second circuit has 10db attenuation at 3Khz and 5Khz frequencies roughly.

Comment: @JonathanS. I am generating 2.5V in my PCB circuit by a voltage divider (with resistors) and then the output is connected to a buffer. From the buffer output, 2.5V is getting connected to the circuit. I tried with a voltage regulator but it's heating due to high output current. ic used for voltage regulator is AMS1117

Comment: @LvW SK bandpass cannot give that high Q. That's why I tried to cascade them. The problem is oscillation at no input.  T&T topology allows variable Q that's why I tried it out but I am facing same issue. Constant output of 4Khz without any input. Do you have any work around or solution that works in PCB not just in simulation. Because all these circuits don't show these behaviour in simulation.

Comment: Is  it 20dB attenuation as you wrote (i.e. output is -20dB from input) or is the output down 20dB from the +30dB passband gain (ie. output is +10dB from input)?

Comment: @Sreya Ghosh what makes you think that a cascade of two second order low-/highpass stages will allow a high-Q bandpass. The opposite is true! Have you ever heard about GIC (Fliege-) Filters?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Ok. I meant at 4Khz center frequency max gain should be 30dB. At 3Khz and 5Khz, 20dB attenuation required i.e it should have gain of 10dB (roughly).

Comment: @SreyaGhosh That's do-able with an LM358  4th order but the characteristics will be affected a bit by the op-amp. I got a centre frequency that was low by 5%. compared to theoretical.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thank you for your suggestion. I have PCB of that 4th order filter but it gives 8Khz oscillation even without any input. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: I think you built it wrong if it is oscillating. This kind of circuit should behave very similarly to simulation. @JonathanS. hinted one thing that could be wrong.

Comment: I have directly supplied 2.5V from the DC source for testing purpose. @SpehroPefhany

Comment: @JonathanS. I have given 2.5V supply directly from DC source. Is it possible that the choice of op amp is wrong for the circuit implementation?

Comment: @SreyaGhosh The cascaded (two-opamp) filter design should be stable, even if your choice of opamp is suboptimal (which the LM358 certainly is). The 8kHz interference is most likely coming from somewhere else, probably from your power supply. Check your supply bypassing and *especially* the quality of the virtual ground. While testing, make sure that the input is not floating, but instead shorted directly to ground with a very short wire. Please also show a complete schematic of your virtual ground circuit.

Comment: @JonathanS. thank you. My virtual ground circuit was coming from the power supply directly. Now I am not using that topology as I could not find the source of oscillation.